# Smartface google push notifications is not clear

Tags: smartface.io

http://api.smartface.io/api/PushNotification/Send/{access_token}.
How can i use it ? can you publish a example please ?How we will send a notificiation from a php script to all users.

Comment: Did you check http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/push-notifications/ ?

Comment: yes i checked but i didnt understand  i would like to write a send.php script i and i wanna push noti to all users

Answer (score 0):

Smartface App Studio offers you push notification services at client side.

You should use a push notification server to send notifications.

```
http://api.smartface.io/api/PushNotification/Send/{access_token}
```

is our test server which is outdated.

For more information about client side processes please read http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/push-notifications

Comment: http://api.smartface.io/api/PushNotification/Send/{access_token}  i have to use this ?  i would like to use like  www.xyz.com/send.php  and i would like to send push noti for all users that uses app

Comment: You can not use it because it is not working anymore. You should find a push services like;
http://urbanairship.com/
http://www.pushapps.mobi/